# Active Android sql

Tags: android, activeandroid

I want sql query for Android in Active Android I was looking and didn't know 
how to do this

```
Select * from  Item
Where  itemno in (0,5)
```

and queries like

```
 Select count(itemName) from Item
 Group by itemname
 Having count(iemName) >5;
```

Is it possible or not? and how?

Answer (score 0):

In android you can execute raw SQL queries using the execSQL method of SQLiteDatabase object.

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("your database name",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TutorialsPoint(Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
```

Check out this tutorial to start with SQLite in Android

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/
```

Answer (score 0):

In **ActiveAndroid** Libray for Android.

You can use the `Select` object of **ActiveAndroid**.

Your query will be like:

```
From select = new Select().from(Item.class);
select = select.where("itemno in (" + firstNumber+","+secondNumber + ")").orderBy("_id DESC");
List<Item> list = select.execute();
```

For more queries refer to [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/)

Hope it helps!!!